# trouble combining array formula and sumproduct (to replace sumif)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumproduct

I have this 2 google spreadsheet where one of them contain whole data and the other act as a dashboard.

in the dashboard sheet, i would like to show a sum of values in data sheet using this fuction:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A9:A),,SUMPRODUCT(IMPORTRANGE("1GuDE-oYK0u9hZBSqRM4EKevW0_wl4ssDVuRedlyj0TA","not deleted!L2:L"),IMPORTRANGE("1GuDE-oYK0u9hZBSqRM4EKevW0_wl4ssDVuRedlyj0TA","not deleted!B2:B")=A9:A)))
```

the A9:A is where the list of data would be used as criterion of the sum in sumproduct.

but the result is

> Array arguments to EQ are of different size.

is there any way that i can use the A9:A as criterion in sumproduct?

Answer (score 0):

The `SUMPRODUCT` function is an [aggregate function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function). If you want to perform a conditional sum by row using `SUMPRODUCT`, you have to use [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) instead of `ARRAYFORMULA`.

```cpp
=MAP(A9:A,
   LAMBDA(a,
     IF(ISBLANK(a),,
        SUMPRODUCT(
          IMPORTRANGE("1GuDE-oYK0u9hZBSqRM4EKevW0_wl4ssDVuRedlyj0TA","not deleted!L2:L"),
          IMPORTRANGE("1GuDE-oYK0u9hZBSqRM4EKevW0_wl4ssDVuRedlyj0TA","not deleted!B2:B")=a))))
```